# CRA 2 with Jest GraphQL Fragment test results in TypeError

Tags: graphql, jestjs, create-react-app, apollo, react-apollo

I have a create-react-app 1.1.4 app that I am trying to upgrade to 2.1.8.

When I upgrade the project to any of the 2.x series of react-scripts, I end up with the following error for tests which contain GraphQL fragments:

```
  TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of undefined

  11 | import {get} from 'lodash';
  12 | 
> 13 | export const GET_ADDRESS = gql`
     |                                ^
  14 |  query ConfirmDeleteAddressGetAddress($addressID: String!, $organisationID: String!) {
  15 |      getSelf {
  16 |          id

  at Object.gql [as default] (node_modules/graphql-tag/src/index.js:162:36)
```

The application itself seems to run fine and if I remove the fragment then it moves on to give me an error on the next fragment.

Jest has gone from version 20.0.4 in my CRA 1.x app to version 23.6 in the CRA 2.1.8 version.

Is there something within the Jest/CRA configuration that could be causing this?

---

Further information on this - if I downgrade graphql to 0.13.2 then the jest test runs but the react app fails to start with:

```
ReferenceError: process is not defined
```